# checking if condition with mysql IN is not working

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables offer_master_catagory and user_profile, I am storing all offer_master_catagory in user_profile table field name user_offers in format 16,17,18.

I am writing a SQl to get all record with offer subscription status yes or no. But i am not getting correct result when i am replacing  user_offers field  dynamic.

```
SELECT omc.id , omc.name,uf.user_offers,
IF(omc.id IN(uf.`user_offers`), 'Yes','No') AS STATUS FROM 
`offer_master_catagory` AS omc 
, `user_profile` AS uf
WHERE omc.status='1' AND omc.lang_code='en' AND uf.user_id='19'
```

When I replace user_offer hardcoded like in(16,17,18) then it is showing correct result.

```
SELECT omc.id , omc.name,uf.user_offers,
IF(omc.id IN(16,17,18), 'Yes','No') AS STATUS FROM 
`offer_master_catagory` AS omc 
, `user_profile` AS uf
WHERE omc.status='1' AND omc.lang_code='en' AND uf.user_id='19'
```

Please suggest solution for this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use `FIND_IN_SET()`

instead of

```
omc.id IN(uf.`user_offers`)
```

try

```
FIND_IN_SET(omc.id, uf.`user_offers`) > 0
```

- [MySQL FIND_IN_SET](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)

---

But the best solution to your problem is to normalize the table properly. DO not store comma separated value in the table.

My suggested schema design is a three-table design wherein it is a `Many-to-Many` relationship,

**user_profile table** (*list all profiles here*)

- userID (PK)
- *other fields...*

**offer_master_catagory table**  (*list all categories for each profile here*)

- userID (FK) (also PK or UQ with column categoryID)
- categoryID (FK)

**category table**  (*list all categories here*)

- categoryID (PK)
- *other fields...*